# Where do I put code of highlighting of last added record?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

My program has two forms - `MainForm(Mainform)` and `SubForm(Add_Student)`. `MainForm` has `Student_DataGridView` which shows all records of students. `SubForm(AddStudent)` adds new students.

My task is  to add new student with `SubForm(Add_Students)`. I done it!:)

Next task is to highlight the newest, latest record in `Student_DataGridView` on `MainForm`. I done it!:)

But I don't know where do I put code of highlighting of last added record. I tried to put in the event:

```
private void MainForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Student_DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1.Selected = true
}
```

But it works always when `MainForm` is shown. And I need to show only after adding new record.  Which is event?

Or where do I put code better?

Comment: How are you adding your new student to the list? Are you passing a new student object back to the parent form from the sub form?

Answer (score 1):

you need to mark the rows as a new one.
I don't know for how long they are new:

- First reload of list after add
- until app is closed
- period of time...

Depending on that there are different solutions.
If you only need it while app is running you can use the Tag property of the row and place a flag in it on creating and deleting it after its not longer new. 
Simplest would be:

```
void SetTag(DataRow row)
{
    row.Tag = true;
}


if(row.Tag != null && row.Tag == true ) Highlight(row);
```

If it should be persistent over more then one start / on different app instances I would create a new field in table to store the flag, date of creation or what ever fits your needs in the database and make it persistent.

Comment: thabks:).  Do I need to mark all rows as new rows and after adding new row will be as the newest row? Can you write code of tagging row. Do tagged rows save in TableAdapter?

Comment: It depends on your need. I don't know how the highlighting should behave. If you want the existing rows to be unmarked after adding of a new row  you have to iterate through the rows and modify / remove the tag.  Things are stored in the Tag are not written to the database. If you want to store it persistent you need to add column of a fitting type (bit, datetime, etc.)to your table and hide this column in your Display Control (GridView I think?).

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:). Maybe this code will be useful for you, so:

```
public int student_count_row = 0;

 private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
   this.StudentTableAdapter.Fill(this.registrationDataSet. Student );  
   student_count_row= Student DataGridView.Rows.Count;
 }


 private void MainForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   this.StudentTableAdapter.Fill(this.registrationDataSet. Student );
   int Student _row = Student DataGridView.Rows.Count;
 if ( Student p_count_row ==   Student_row)
 {
        //We do never here in this condition
             ;
 }
   if ( Student _row > Student _count_row)
 {
 int k = 0;
   k = Student DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
   this.StudentDataGridView.CurrentCell = this.StudentDataGridView[2, k];
   student_count_row =   student_row;
 } 


 }
```

`enter code here`